# Want suggestions in DialogFlow prompt statement

Tags: bots, chatbot, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm developing dialog flow chatbot, I want to give suggestions in my PROMPT question like Google gives for sign-in, how to do this?

suggestions are simple like "LEFT" and "RIGHT", such kind of static.

[image: I want something like this]

[image]
This is where I want to show options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as a ["quick reply" rich response](https://dialogflow.com/docs/rich-messages#quick_replies). Unfortunately, it isn't possible to use rich responses in prompts, as these can only be text.

If you want more flexibility in the way you prompt users for more information, you can use [follow-up intents](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents#follow-up_intents) and [contexts](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents#contexts) to handle the logical flow of the conversation.

Comment: or you can handle the prompt with reach responses, Programmatically xD

Comment: Good point, @NikhilSavaliya. If you're working entirely in the Dialogflow console, this isn't possible, but you can handle this however you like in your own code if you're only using Dialogflow as an NLU system.

Comment: @techpeace Exactly, that's the approach I do in my development